node installation error and how to delete chocolatey folder on my hp folio 9470 laptop
How do I locate the 'C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin\choco.exe' folder on my hp folio laptop? I need to delete it so I can reinstall Node. I have tried my best to get it done, but to no avail. I would appreciate it if I can get a solution.

By default on Windows installations, the C:\ProgramData folder is hidden. You can get to that folder by putting the path C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin\ into explorer, or enabling viewing hidden files and folders in Explorer's view options - but I would caution you to not just wildly delete folders if you don't understand what they're doing, or why you're doing it. You shouldn't need to delete that folder (which you have written as an executable) in order to reinstall Node. Perhaps rephrasing the question with more information would help?
